# How does one create a DIV that appears in the bottom corner of the window (after a set amount of time)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to create a "LiveChat Offering" pop-up that appears in the bottom of the screen after our visitors arrive at a specific page, and have been on that page for say 30 seconds or so. I would like to keep the code jQuery/CSS if at all possible.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">Some jQuery that will change the 'display:hidden;' to 'display:block;' on the DIV after 30 seconds</script>

<div id="live-chat" style="position:absolute;bottom:0px; right:100px;z-index:5;display:none;>
 <h4>Need Help?</h4>
 <p>Click the link below for assistance</p>
 <a href="live-chat.php">Chat with a salesman</a>
</div>
```

Comment: ... and what's wrong with your current HTML + CSS?

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` to create a timer.

Comment: Do _you_ want to create this or do you want someone else to create it for you?

Comment: It would be nice to have some -webkit CSS transitions incorporated as well. But I mainly need some direction with the jQuery and/or Javascript if needed...

Comment: I would like to learn how to do this myself for sure...

Comment: I am attempting to use the setTimeout() right now, I'm just very new to jQuery/Java

Comment: @Richard, my HTML is fine, I am just seeking some guidance on the scripting side.

Comment: @derekmx271 ~ then it'd be nice if you can post the scripts you've tried as well. Personally, it helps me point you to the stuff you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

setTimeout(function() {
$("#live-chat").css({ "display" : "block" });
}, 30000); // 30 seconds in MS


}); 
</script>

<div id="live-chat" style="position:absolute;bottom:0px; right:100px;z-index:5;display:none;>
 <h4>Need Help?</h4>
 <p>Click the link below for assistance</p>
 <a href="live-chat.php">Chat with a salesman</a>
</div>
```

Good luck!

**Edit:**

For sliding it in:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

// Store our panel into a variable.
var $myPanel = $("#live-chat");

// Get the height of the panel dynamically.
var $myPanelHeight = parseInt($myPanel.height());

// Immediately set the opacity to 0 - to hide it and set its bottom to minus its height.
$myPanel.css({ "opacity" : 0, "bottom" : "-" + $myPanelHeight + "px" });

// Set a timeout for the panel to slide and fade in.
setTimeout(function() {

$myPanel.animate({

    // The CSS properties we want to animate (opacity and bottom position).
    opacity: 1,
    bottom: '0'

  }, 2000, function() {

    // Animation complete. 
    // You can put other code here to do something after it has slid-in.

  });

}, 30000); // 30 seconds in MS


}); 
</script>

<div id="live-chat" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right:100px; z-index:5;">
 <h4>Need Help?</h4>
 <p>Click the link below for assistance</p>
 <a href="live-chat.php">Chat with a salesman</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Right on, I'll give that a try. Looks like that would do the trick!

Comment: This worked for me. Added some additional (cosmetic) styles to the DIV and voila! This code is perfect though. Thanks so much!

Comment: How would I incorporate a slideIn effect (jQuery) into this? Would I need to use the css 'visibilty' attribute, or can I use a jQuery slide effect instead?

Comment: You can use the jQuery animate() method, which allows you to animate on some (not all) CSS properties. See my edit above for an example. I haven't test this code, so let me know if it doesn't work. Basically, with JS, I calculate the height of your panel and offset its bottom property off screen. Then I animate this in. As an added bonus, I put in an opacity thing too...so it will slide AND fade in at the same time. If you don't want this, simply remove references to the opacity fade stuff. Hope that helps.

Comment: You sir are a baller... I am attempting to make this guy reverse the animation now after a few seconds. Returning to the bottom...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you already got the position part, and you are asking about the delay part?

Something with `setTimeout` like this could work

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#live-chat').show();
  }, [delay in ms]);
}
```

You probably also want to change the `.show()` to have some kind of effect to alert the user that it appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delay function of jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var miliseconds = 30000 //30 seconds
    $("#live-chat").delay(miliseconds).hide();
}
```

here is a jsfiddle example for your code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJsR8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The following is a starting point that has the functionality I asked for :) Thanks everyone! I used Michael's example...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

 setTimeout(function() {
 $("#live-chat").css({ "display" : "block" });
 }, 5000); // 30 seconds in MS


}); 
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="live-chat" style="width:250px; height:150px; position:absolute; bottom:0px; right:100px; z-index:5; display:none; border:#ccc 1px dashed;">
 <h4>Need Help?</h4>
 <p>Click the link below for assistance</p>
 <a href="live-chat.php">Chat with a salesman</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will most likely add some more script that will hide the window after 20 seconds, which should be easy using the same script above to return it to a hidden state. Thanks guys :)

Comment: No worries. See my edit above for additional slide in and fade in.